# Updating login code to MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to update this section of old MySQL code to run with MySQLi. I am aware that the `MySQL_return function` was removed and I've tried a couple things but not too sure how to convert this code to run with MySQLi? Any ideas or help would be appreciated.

```
function user_id_from_username($email_address, $conn) {
    return mysql_return(mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT `userid` FROM `users` WHERE `email_address` = '$email_address'"), 0, 'userid');
}


function login($email_address, $password, $conn) {
    $userid = user_id_from_username($email_address);

    $password = md5($password);

    return  (mysql_return(mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT COUNT(`userid`) FROM `users` WHERE `email_address` = '$email_address' AND `password` = '$password'"), 0) ==1) ? $userid : false;

}
```

I have attempted such edits as:

```
function user_id_from_username($email_address, $conn) {
    return mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT `userid` FROM `users` WHERE `email_address` = '$email_address'"), 0, 'userid');
}


function login($email_address, $password, $conn) {
    $userid = user_id_from_username($email_address);

    $password = md5($password);

    return  (mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT COUNT(`userid`) FROM `users` WHERE `email_address` = '$email_address' AND `password` = '$password'"), 0) ==1) ? $userid : false;

}
```

But no luck. Any advice or examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `$mysqli->query();` returns a `$mysqli_result` if the query was executed successfully, `FALSE` otherwise. Then you can call `fetch_assoc();` for get the first row from the query. The resultant array will be in the form of an associative array. Here is some documentation you should read:
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php and
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

```
function getIdFromEmail($email) {
  $emailSanitized=mysqli_real_escape_string($email);
  $mysqli=new mysqli("host","user","password","dbName");
  $res=$mysqli->query("SELECT `userid` FROM `users` WHERE `email_address`='$emailSanitized'");
  $retArray=$res->fetch_assoc();
  return $retArray['userId'];      
}
```

Comment: Why not a prepared statement?

Comment: @Gumbo That would be even better

Comment: Okay, so would the same effect work for the login function as well?

Comment: function login($email_address, $password) {
 $userid = user_id_from_username($email_address);
 
 $password = md5($password);
 $res=$conn->query("SELECT COUNT(`userid`) FROM `users` WHERE `email_address` = '$email_address' AND `password` = '$password'");
 $retArray=$res->fetch_assoc();
  return $retArray;
 
}

Comment: I've configured it to that, but not sure if it's correct?

Comment: The solution you proposed returns the whole record. If you just want to know if the user is logged in you can use something like function login($email_address, $password) { $userid = user_id_from_username($email_address); $password = md5($password); $res=$conn->query("SELECT COUNT(userid) AS isLogged FROM users WHERE email_address = '$email_address' AND password = '$password'"); $retArray=$res->fetch_assoc(); return $retArray['isLogged']; }